# Confidence range for individual prediction from multiple regression

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I've built a multivariate regression model for predicting the price of an item given a couple of other factors about that item - age, condition, etc. So, given values for age and condition I can return a single value for price.

But what I want to do is return a price *range*, representing, say, 95% confidence that the true value will fall within this range.

I've googled a bunch, but I can't find a clear description of how to achieve this. The closest I've come is what's described in this paper: http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=7&n=2, in the section "Calculating a Predicted Score, and Confidence Intervals Around That Score".

Given that the confidence of a regression model "bows" in around the mean for each value, I feel like this is more complex than just taking +/-X% of the predicted value. The range should be greater for items that are at the extremes of age and condition, right?

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Bayesian regression would give you these uncertainties through the posterior. Look up [Gaussian process regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. The specific implementation requirements strongly favour a simple linear regression, but it is possible I could do something more complex.